# moduleDirectories key does not make it possible to import my test utils

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test my Expo React Native app with Jest and `@testing-lib/react-native`.

I have the following set up in my `package.json`.

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "test-utils"
    ]
  },
```

And my folder structure looks like this:

```
├──node_modules/
├──test-utils/
├──src/
└──package.json
```

`src/` contains the test files. I'm testing my configuration with this simple test at `src/index.test.js`:

```js
import { assert } from 'test-utils';

const sum = (a, b) => a + b;

describe('sum', () => {
  assert({
    given: 'two numbers',
    should: 'add the numbers',
    actual: sum(1, 3),
    expected: 4,
  });
});
```

Where `assert` is in `test-utils/index.js`:

```js
const assert = ({
  given = undefined,
  should = '',
  actual = undefined,
  expected = undefined,
} = {}) => {
  it(`given ${given}: should ${should}`, () => {
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
};

export { assert };
```

If I run my tests I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'test-utils' from 'index.test.js'
```

Why is that? I mean I have configured the `moduleDirectories` key?  How can you fix this? I'd really love to be able to import `assert` as an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The docs are just bad at the moment.

If you have this folder structure

```sh
├──node_modules/
├──src/
├──utils/
└──package.json
```

Then you want to name your module directories like this:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "@testing-library/react-native/cleanup-after-each"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "utils"
  ]
},
```

Then **within `utils/`** you want to have the `.js` file `test-utils.js`. Then you can import from `test-utils` in your tests.

So, the key take away is that the name of the module from which you export has to be the name of the `.js` file. And the folder that you put into `moduleDirectories` has to contain this `.js` file.

Comment: Does this configuration is in a `jest.config.js` file ?

Comment: @snoobdogg Should work there, too, but this one is from `package.json.`